# What is the most pythonic way to solve a differential equation using the Euler method?

Tags: python, mathematics, numpy

For example, with this differential equation, how can I do it in a pythonic way?

```
dx/dt=f(x,t)
```

I have a way to do it, but I think this is not the most pythonic way:

```
import numpy as np
dt=0.01
N_iter=10./dt
def f(x,t):
    return x**2*t#insert your favorite function here
x=np.zeros(N_iter)
for i in range(N_iter-1):
    x[i+1]=x[i]+dt*f(x[i],i*dt)
```

Comment: What was wrong with [`scipy.integrate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html)?

Comment: What makes you think the code isn't Pythonic? (apart from PEP8 issues)

Comment: Well I thought that there was only one pythonic way to do something and I was wondering if I was doing it right. The problem with 'scipy.integrate' is that I must do each step in turn inside a loop.

Comment: @NunoCalaim: Have you looked at [`scipy.integrate.odeint`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html)?

Answer (score 3):

Using a `for` loop is not an *unpythonic* way at all. Instead, an Euler method could be implemented with a recursive function, but it not necessary and less optimized in Python.

However, methods for [vectorizing recursive sequences](http://numpy-discussion.10968.n7.nabble.com/vectorizing-recursive-sequences-td35532.html) are discussed on the numpy-discussion mailing-list. I encourage you to use structures like `for` loops in such situations. You will minimize the risk of errors by writing simple and concise codes.